# How to, using JPath, select collection items having a child with specified value?

Tags: c#, json.net

I'm using `SelectTokens()` from Newtonsoft Json.Net.
I'm trying to select values from a list of objects where each of them has a natural key and a value.

```
jobAsJObject.SelectTokens("$.SeparatedContexts[.ContextName='default']")
```

I can't figure that out because none of the examples that I found covers selecting items based on child properties.

Comment: Alternatively, can you recommend some simmilar library to select elements in dynamic object or JSON string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Documentation for JSONPath queries can be found at [Querying JSON with JSONPath](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryJsonSelectTokenJsonPath.htm) and [JSONPath - XPath for JSON](http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/).  Among other things, you can filter arrays for children with specific property values.  The syntax is:

> ```
> [?(@.PropertyName='PropertyValue')]
> ```

Thus, to select all elements with property `'ContextName' : 'default'` in an array named `'SeparatedContexts'`, do:

```
var tokens = jobAsJObject.SelectTokens("SeparatedContexts[?(@.ContextName == 'default')]");
```

Of course, you could always just append a Linq [`Where`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549418%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) clause instead:

```
var token = jobAsJObject.SelectTokens("SeparatedContexts[*]")
                        .Where(o => (string)o.SelectToken("ContextName") == "default");
```

Working [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/2mfjZ8).

Comment: The "?" char... I see... Thank you very much.